# Firefox - can't refresh cached video file

Tags: html, firefox, video, firefox-developer-tools

Edited to clarify the underlying question.

I am trying to debug a simple HTML5 webpage containing one image and one video. Everything displays fine. The video plays correctly. But, when I try to refresh the page, everything is downloaded except the video file. I am using the Firefox developer tools but I can't understand what is going on.

On the network tab I see the `.html` file being downloaded, then the `image.jpg` file. But I never see the `video.mp4` file downloaded. The video plays OK, but it is not the current version on the server. It seems to be a previous version that has been cached.

I'm mystified why this should be. The cache is disabled in developer tools. I'm refreshing the page with `Ctrl+F5`. It's as if the video is being served from some secret local cache that I don't know about. I'm using Firefox 47.0.1. The same thing also happens when I test with Firebug.

Edit. I have now tried Developer Tools in Chrome and it's exactly the same. The very first time I access the page, I can see `video.mp4` being downloaded. On subsequent reloads, I see the `.html` and `.jpg` files normally, but **not** the `video.mp4` file. It must be cached somewhere because it plays. I disabled the cache in Chrome Dev Tools. I cleared the cache explicitly and tried an incognito window. Apart from the very first time, I never see any indication of the video file being downloaded.

I must be missing something obvious. Can anyone else reproduce this?

Here is my HTML.

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Test page.</p>
    <img src="media/image.jpg">
    <video src="media/video.mp4" controls="">
      Display this if the browser can't play video.
    </video>
  </body>
```

Information moved from comments on an answer to the question:
**1:**
Thanks @nakji. Clearing the cache and private browsing made no difference at all. But closing the browser did. I reopened the browser after clearing the cache. On my very first access to the page I could see two GETs for `video.mp4` with responses 206 (Partial Content). But after that it was back to the original problem. I will download Chrome and try that

**2:**
@ManoDestro. I tried everything possible to force a fresh download of `video.mp4`. But it's not happening. I reloaded the page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. I turned off caching in Dev Tools settings. I cleared the cache manually. I tried a private browsing window. I can't think of anything else. It's like the video is served from a secret cache that doesn't obey the normal caching rules. I have used multiple tools to confirm that the file is not coming down the wire - FF Dev Tools, Firebug, and now Wireshark. Can someone please test with a similar setup?

Answer (score 6):

After a whole day's Googling I can now answer my own question. It turns out that Firefox has a special "media cache" for HTML5 video and audio content which is **completely separate** from the regular cache that everyone knows about. It is optimised for the high bandwidth and huge files associated with media content. One of the devs, Robert O'Callahan explains it all [here](http://robert.ocallahan.org/2009/04/media-cache_02.html).

The dumb thing is that this media cache doesn't seem to get cleared when you would expect it to. In fact it never seems to get cleared. Ever. The result is that Firefox keeps serving up stale content from the cache when you really want it to fetch the media file again from the server. This was the problem I was trying to debug originally. Firefox kept playing the wrong video after I changed the file on the server. I couldn't get it to download the new version.

All the things you normally do to force a page reload don't work with the media cache. The following have no effect.

- The user selects 'Clear recent history' and deletes everything.
- The user turns off caching in Developer tools.
- The user forces a complete page reload with Ctrl+F5.

The only thing that does work is closing the browser and starting again. I'm still finding my way around this complex area. If anyone knows any more about it, please comment.

I reported this as a bug to Firefox [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1290318#c0).

Comment: Based on the contents of the linked page, it may be possible to change `media.cache_size` to `0`, or a very small value, in `about:config`. This might be effective if done to either keep it at that new value, or set it low for a time or for some action and then return to the original value. Doing so for other than from one session (set->restart FF->use->return to orig value->restart FF) will depend on when that value is checked and if it is checked more than once per FF session.  Looks like it is time to [RTFS](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?q=media.cache_size&redirect=false).

Comment: Seems like it's regressed in 60.8.0esr :|